# Remove dependency from other dependency?

Tags: java, maven

How to remove dependency from other dependency

**For example:**
   I use parent child project in maven, When I create build of main module `jar` then I have no issue, but when I create child maven module `jar` then I got a error in starting application .

```
2019-01-03 17:46:56.100  INFO 9764 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-01-03 17:46:56.215  INFO 9764 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
roup.com:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2019-01-03 17:46:56.229 ERROR 9764 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :
>***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.
Action:
Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8080, or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

So any way to remove dependency.

Comment: As the log says, your problem is that your app is trying to listen on port 8080, but there is another process listening  on that port

Comment: *Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8080*.. is not at all related to the dependencies.

Comment: i want to use tomcat in parent library but don't want to use in child 
 library.I use parent library as a dependency in child project, So parent library dependency have tomcat.

Comment: This seems to be a runtime issue, not something with dependencies. The tomcat does not start automatically by adding a dependency, right?

Comment: @JFMeier  I didn't explicitly started or configured tomcat, But I can see tomcat starting in console. Please guide if I'm doing anything wrong with springBoot anotation ?